# Altering survey data in R

Tags: r

I have a set of observational heath survey data. I want to modify the source identifier so that I can still have a number of sources identified, but the original ID is not the tracking ID to keep confidentiality. I am having trouble figuring it out.

Here's the basic layout of the dataframe

```
ID  
30

30
30
30
24
24
24
```

I want to create a newID so that the data would look like the following

```
NewID   ID  
1       30   
1       30
1       30
1       30
2       24
2       24
2       24
```

Answer (score 4):

if your data frame is df then this should do it.

```
 df$NewID <- as.numeric(factor(df$ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

`cbind(match(ID,unique(ID)),ID)`

Answer (score 0):

`rle`is useful here:

```
> ID <- rep(c(30,24), c(4,3)) # your data
> ind <- rle(ID)$lengths
> data.frame(ID, newID=rep(c(1,length(ind)), ind ))
  ID newID
1 30     1
2 30     1
3 30     1
4 30     1
5 24     2
6 24     2
7 24     2
```

`transform` is also another alternative

```
> transform(ID, newID=rep(c(1,2),   rle(ID)$lengths))
```